# A command line that yields the complete URL of a file inside the svn repository?

Tags: svn

I am inside a directory in svn, I want to tell something another developer about a file there over chat.

Is there an easy command to obtain the full URL to that file - let's say something he can send as a parameter to svn export or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
svn info «your_file» | grep URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Like "svn info" [file]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do.  It does the additional step of copying it to the clipboard so you can paste into a browser or email:

getUrl.bat:

```
@echo off

svn info %1 | grep URL | sed -e s/URL://g | clip
```

This assumes you've got [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and clip.exe installed and on your PATH.  Clip.exe is in most recent versions of windows (after 2k3 Server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svn info --xml` to generate an XML dump of all information data. And you can use `xmllint --xpath` to exactly extract the right data. The small wrapper [svninfo](http://ceving.blogspot.de/2013/11/reading-subversion-information-in.html) simplifies the use:

```
svninfo /info/entry/url
```

For the URL a simple `grep` might be sufficient, but for other values an exact XPath expression is more reliable than `grep`.